# Перенос текста Label JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

У меня есть Label(библиотека JavaFX) Как реализовать перенос текста на новую строчку?

Comment: Установите у Label свойство setWrapText в true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
describeBook.setMaxWidth(80);
describeBook.setWrapText(true);
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]